# Does particular string match strings in text file

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a text file containing many words (single word on each line). I have to read in each word, modify the words, and then check if the modified word matches any of the words in the file. I am having trouble with the last part (it is the hasMatch method in my code). It sounds simple enough and I know what I should do, but whatever I try does not work.

```
#read in textfile 
myFile = open('good_words.txt')


#function to remove first and last character in string, and reverse string
def modifyString(str):
    rmFirstLast = str[1:len(str)-2] #slicing first and last char
    reverseStr = rmFirstLast[::-1] #reverse string 
    return reverseStr

#go through list of words to determine if any string match modified string
def hasMatch(modifiedStr):
    for line in myFile:
        if line == modifiedStr:
            print(modifiedStr + " found")
        else:
            print(modifiedStr + "not found")

for line in myFile:
    word = str(line) #save string in line to a variable

    #only modify strings that are greater than length 3
    if len(word) >= 4:
        #global modifiedStr #make variable global
        modifiedStr = modifyString(word) #do string modification
        hasMatch(modifiedStr)

myFile.close()
```

Comment: The file object  is being consumed by that outer `for` loop. The inner loop in `hasMatch` will not do what you think it does

Comment: And `word = str(line)` is not necessary. `line` is already a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here

1. you have to strip the lines or you get linefeed/CR chars that fail the match
2. you have to read the file once and for all or the file iterator runs out after the first time
3. the speed is bad: sped up for the search using a `set` instead of a `list`
4. the slicing is overly complicated and wrong: `str[1:-1]` does it (thanks to those who commented my answer)
5. The whole code is really to long & complex. I summed it up in a few lines.

code:

```
#read in textfile
myFile = open('good_words.txt')
# make a set (faster search), remove linefeeds
lines = set(x.strip() for x in myFile)
myFile.close()

# iterate on the lines
for word in lines:
    #only consider strings that are greater than length 3
    if len(word) >= 4:
        modifiedStr = word[1:-1][::-1] #do string modification
        if modifiedStr in lines:
            print(modifiedStr + " found (was "+word+")")
        else:
            print(modifiedStr + " not found")
```

I tested the program on a list of common english words and I got those matches:

```
so found (was most)
or found (was from)
no found (was long)
on found (was know)
to found (was both)
```

Edit: another version which drops the `set` and uses `bisect` on the sorted list to avoid hashing/hash collisions.

```
import os,bisect

#read in textfile
myFile = open("good_words.txt"))
lines = sorted(x.strip() for x in myFile) # make a sorted list, remove linefeeds
myFile.close()

result=[]
for word in lines:

    #only modify strings that are greater than length 3
    if len(word) >= 4:
        modifiedStr = word[1:-1][::-1] #do string modification
        # search where to insert the modified word
        i=bisect.bisect_left(lines,modifiedStr)
        # if can be inserted and word is actually at this position: found
        if i<len(lines) and lines[i]==modifiedStr:
            print(modifiedStr + " found (was "+word+")")
        else:
            print(modifiedStr + " not found")
```

Comment: Good answer, also `rmFirstLast = str[1:len(str)-2]` should be `str[1:len(str)-1]`

Comment: There's nothing like `strip(x)`. You meant `x.strip()`

Comment: I take it back, str[1:-1]

Comment: How do you get `O(nlog(n))`?

Comment: I have a feeling there's something not right with the OPs logic here... They appear to be wanting to match a modified string against modified strings... it'd make more sense as an exercise to look for modified strings that are equal to their *original* in the wordlist...

Comment: @NinjaPuppy: not possible since the modified words are _shorter_ than the original words. one possible (real word) candidate: `fin` vs `knife` (it's a pseudo palindrom-search algorithm)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham loop on n and log(n) search with the set (well I assume search in set is log(n) at least it is much faster than the original (non-working) O(n**2).

Comment: A set lookup bar collisions is constant.

Comment: @NinjaPuppy: yes you're right my goal is to match the modified string against strings in the original text file. E.g., knife -> fin, and then search for "fin" in the text file. Sorry if I made it confusing.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre that's what I meant :p Note that `set` will take any iterable, so you can avoid building a list to only discard it: eg: `lines = set([x.strip() for x in myFile])` -> `set(x.strip() for x in myFile)`

Comment: @StackimusPrime I admit a list of input words and expected words would have been better for us (and for you). Does my answer fix your problems in the end? (I'm lost right now :))

Comment: Using the system shared dictionary I get `{'prettily', 'delivers', 'prepping', 'delivery', 'revilers', 'medullas', 'medullae', 'legalism', 'prettify'}` for 8 letters... which is kinda nifty :)

Comment: @NinjaPuppy: admit it, you're alluding you're beginning to like it :) Where diid you find this database BTW?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy I use windows. It only knows `dir, cd, del, mkdir` :) I'm upvoting the question just because it is funny (`atropine found (was reniportal)`). BTW if I drop the `set` it crawls like hell!!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I added another implementation just for you :) Well, you tell me, but there are no collisions with bisect. It is really a real O(n*log(n)) now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122592/discussion-between-ninja-puppy-and-jean-francois-fabre).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: thanks for much for your help. I appreciate it. I only made a few minor changes to what you had and it ended up working at the end. I just started using python so sorry if I made things confusing.

Comment: @ jean, yes the second is n log n, the first is linear as a set lookup is O(1) on average bar collisions as I previously mentioned which in reality is very unlikely. Why did you think using a set meant log n lookups?

Comment: Also the worst case using a set if you had all collisions would also be quadratic not log n

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're not slicing just the first and last character but the first and last two characters.

```
rmFirstLast = str[1:len(str)-2]
```

Change that to:

```
rmFirstLast = str[1:len(str)-1]
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice them.

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing this out. I have it set to slice the last two characters because I tested it with just -1 (instead of -2) and it did not work...maybe an empty char has something to do with it.